# FP calculation problem with multicolumn

Tags: multicolumn, width, fp

I want to do a calculation inside tabular environment, 
My tabular look like this

```
\documentclass{book} 
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{fp}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|*{4}{c|}}
\hline
a & b & c & d  \\
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{a} & b \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.5\textwidth}|}{a} & b & c\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But now I want to change the width and number of columns with FP. I tried something like

```
\documentclass{book} 
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{fp}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|*{4}{c|}}
\hline
a & b & c & d  \\
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{a} & b \\
\hline
\FPmul\one{2}{2}
\FPdiv\two{1}{2}
\multicolumn{\one}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\two\textwidth}|}{a} & b & c\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

And I got the following error:

> ```
> ( FP-MUL ) ( FP-DIV )
> ! Misplaced \omit.
> \multispan ->\omit 
>                    \@multispan 
> l.13 ...ng\arraybackslash}p{  \two\textwidth}|}{a}
>                                                    & b & c\\
> ```

any help ? :/

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: `\multicolumn` should appear as the first item in the cell. The `fp` computations make TeX start a cell, so it's too late for `\multicolumn`.

Comment: And how can i do it? maybe without fp ? :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\multicolumn` should appear as the first item in the cell. The `fp` computations make TeX start a cell, so it's too late for `\multicolumn`. You can use `xfp` instead:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xfp}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|*{4}{c|}}
\hline
a & b & c & d  \\
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{a} & b \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\fpeval{1/2}\textwidth}|}{a} & b & c\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For the first argument to `\multicolumn` there is `\inteval`.